# How do i tell Webpack to only/always use versions shown in package json?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, draftjs

I am trying to contribute to an npm package (react-draft-wysiwyg) but keep getting (what i think are) Webpack errors.

First i try to click the embed button of draft-js and it errors saying "block is not a BlockNode" - then i follow blogs/posts like this https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/1763 
i match peer dependencies and main project pkg json dependencies to draft-js v0.10.4, re-yarn and it says

```
Element ref was specified as a string (editorContainer) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You may be adding a ref to a function component
2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
3. You have multiple copies of React loaded
```

So in my project's webpack.config.js i have:

```
alias: {
        react: path.resolve('node_modules/react'),
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "app"), "node_modules"],
      },
```

I really think these issues are stemming from the webapp trying to pull in different versions of react from the local yarn link'd one.

How do i tell Webpack to only ever use top-level, over everything else?

Help?

Comment: `npm ls draft-js`, show what you get.

Comment: thanks @PlayMa256 - i get the following...

```
➜  cms git:(master) ✗ npm ls draft-js
ui-comps@0.1.0 /Users/adrianthompson/Documents/proj/cms
├── draft-js@0.10.5
├─┬ react-draft-wysiwyg@1.13.0 -> /Users/adrianthompson/Desktop/local-packages/react-draft-wysiwyg
│ └── draft-js@0.10.4  extraneous
└─┬ react-rte@0.16.1
  └── draft-js@0.10.5  deduped

npm ERR! extraneous: draft-js@0.10.4 /Users/adrianthompson/Documents/proj/cms/node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/node_modules/draft-js

```

Comment: As i expected it is not webpack faults, it is npm fault. Try running npm dedupe then see if 0.10.5 is the only one. That happened with webpack as well unfortunately